# ModelBinding a List of ViewModels with the MvcContrib Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, mvccontrib-grid

I'm trying to bind a list of model objects to a grid using the MvcContrib Grid helper. Obviously, emitting an HTML table is easy enough, but I'm struggling with returning all the selected rows (or all rows and filtering via a Where(x => x.Selected)).

Here's a dummy version of what I mean:

Model:

```
public class Player
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int JerseyNumber { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model democode.Models.Player    
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @{
    var grid = Html.Grid(Model)
               .AutoGenerateColumns()
               .Columns(c => c.For(p => Html.CheckBoxFor(_ => p.Selected)).InsertAt(0))
               .Columns(c => c.For(p => Html.HiddenFor(_ => p.Id)))
        grid.Render();
     }

     <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
     </p>
}
```

So, what you are looking at is a grid of hockey players with a checkbox before each one, allowing the user to select one or more. On clicking submit, I'd like for it to post the collection back (understanding that all but Selected and Id would be null/default), but I understand the problem is that the records coming across in the POST data have overlapping keys in the list of key-value pairs. 
I have successfully worked around this in the past by hand-writing the HTML table and using the strategy Phil Haack outlines here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

My question is, can I do the same thing using the Grid helper from MvcContrib, or is it more work than what it's worth?